# Hardware Requirements - Mosquitto MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, system, mosquitto

We are going to implement a Mosquitto MQTT Broker in windows system.

Around 25 MQTT clients going to publish a parameters in 2000 different topics (Topic/Subtopic). How can I calculate the system requirements for installing Mosquitto MQTT Broker?

Comment: You can't based on the information you've provided. More important is things like message rate, size of messages, are you using retained messages and at what QOS. As with most things you will have to setup a representative test and benchmark it.

Comment: any document or guide for the same? Apart from Mosquitto MQTT Broker, for any MQTT broker installation how to derive the system/hardware requirements?

Comment: Like @hardlib said, you need to test and benchmark yourself. The documentation for that is Mosquitto's documentation. But 25 clients is not a lot. If they're not sending large messages and not transmitting often (many times per second) you shouldn't need much computer to handle them. But, as hardlib said, it depends on what you're doing. If they're sending large messages that are being retained, you may need a lot of memory. The information you gave is not enough to even guess.